# Font icons are blank only on the Windows version of .Maui app

Tags: xaml, maui, maui-windows

In building a .Maui app we have got the windows version working. However unlike the android and IOS version, the windows version is not loading any of our Fontawesome icons.

They are not blank squares like I have seen other people get, they are just totally blank.
[image]

The MauiProgram.cs has this line:

```
fonts.AddFont("font-awesome-solid.otf", "font-awesome-solid");
```

And an example of an icon not working would be this line:

```
<customcontrols:CustomButton     
  Grid.Column="1"
  Grid.Row="2"
  x:Name="NextButton"
  Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.buttonTextNextPage}"
  Clicked="OnNextButtonClicked">

  <Button.ImageSource>
    <FontImageSource FontFamily="font-awesome-solid"
      Glyph="{x:Static fonts:FontAwesome.CaretRight}"
      Size="32" />
  </Button.ImageSource>
</customcontrols:CustomButton>
```

I've tried searching and am now totally stumped, any ideas would be appreciated!

EDIT: I thought I better give what is inside CustomButton as I feel the issue may be there

```
 public CustomButton() {
        this.SetDynamicResource(VisualElement.StyleProperty, SystemConstant.CustomButtonStyle);
    }

    private string _glyphName = null;

    public string Glyph { 
        get 
        {
            return _glyphName;
        }
        set
        {
            _glyphName = value;
            var fis = new FontImageSource
            {
                FontFamily = "font-awesome-solid#",
                Glyph = value,
                Size = 25,
            };
            fis.SetDynamicResource(FontImageSource.ColorProperty, "LabelTextColor");
            this.ImageSource = fis;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You know, I actually am not too sure where I got that font from. I believe it was just from the fontawesome website, but maybe the previous version. Would there be a specific issue with that version?

Comment: You can try to set a minimum height for the `CustomButton` on windows and try again.

Comment: If the font is in a class library, that would be a different assembly. If that's the case, you have to use AddEmbeddedResourceFont instead of AddFont so that you can specify the correct assembly.

Comment: Oh, interesting. I have never heard that before. How would I know if the font was in a class library?

Comment: Oh, I only just saw the idea to set a minimum height, apologies. However I cannot seem to set a MinHeight - I get the generic No property/even found for "MinHeight"

Comment: Could you please share the full code of `CustomButton` ?

Comment: A bit of a delay on this (I was away) but I edited the question to include the code for custom button. Though I am not so sure this is where my issue lies

Answer (score 0):

Bit of an anticlimactic answer, but it seems that all we did was an update to dotnet as well as some of our libraries.
So despite never figuring out what the issue was, the update have resolved the issue and the icons are now visible in windows